# Varchar vs Number for a Surrogate Primary Key(not a natural key)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

What is in your opinion the better choice for a surrogate primary key, the number or the varchar? In our case we use a varchar2(15) so not a very large column?

I won't reopen the thread regarding natural vs surrogate keys usage.
We use a primary key column (aka surrogate key) generated automatically and an User Key(aka natural key) for the business keyy. We have no concerns that writing SQL will have to join many tables.
Using a Varchar in the Primary Key we have the possibility to use a prefix followed by a sequence generated number converted to a string. This allows partitioning based on that prefix value.

Thank you. rimetnac

Comment: Well - your question seems to answer it self in that you actually plan on having non-numbers in your key?

Comment: Numbers are perfectly suited for usage in partitioning, no ? If they are given sequentially, that is, not if given randomly.

Answer (score 1):

One threat you could possibly face when using `varchar2`-typed primary keys is that with `nls_comp = linguistic` the Oracle optimizer will suddenly stop using index lookups via primary key columns due to automatic internal varchar2-column-predicates modifications. And I believe that in some cases it might stop doing partition pruning as well. Of course, it can be fixed programmatically, but it still is some work on top of your project plan.

Second threat is a potentially incorrect query cost arithmetic. I don't remember *how incorrect* it is, you'll have to look up e.g. Jonathan Lewis' "Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals" book yourself, read the relevant sections and do your own research for your Oracle version in use.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, VARCHAR value requires about to twice more space than equal NUMBER value. That's why VARCHAR primary key means double-sized primary key index, worse index search, worse utilization of buffer cache and so on. I doubt if it good design, especially if data large enough to partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

You are causing yourself needless problems with the design you describe. First, you have a natural key that uniquely identifies each tuple. But you've elected to use a surrogate key as the Primary Key. That's fine so far. Now you introduce an unnamed attribute that separates the tuples into logical groupings. That's fine too. But why do you want to combine it with the PK? What is gained by that? The grouping you want can be performed just as well (and in many ways much better) by keeping this attribute separate.

In combining this attribute with the PK, it loses it's identity so to speak. It would be like combining the StudentID of each student with the name of the major in a university database. There are any number of reasons to group according to major, but now there is no specific "Major" field but a "Major_SID" amalgam. One problem that is immediately obvious is switching majors. Updating a "Major" field is easy. Updating just the "Major" part of a concatenated string while leaving the other part unchanged is more difficult.

Such additional problems are not insurmountable and could well be worth it if the benefits were greater. Does this method provide such overriding benefits? Does it provide any benefits at all?

Minus such benefits, my advice is to keep the grouping attribute separate. That will also keep the surrogate key anonymous as to the contents of the tuple. As well as keeping it numeric, which is easier to sort on than text.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no unique natural key for varchar, use autoincrement int.